# Relative parent ignored with absolutely positioned children

Tags: html, css, css-position

I know that there are a lot of questions about positioning out there, including about absolute positioning inside a relative parent.

I've read many of these questions and found a informative link on css-tricks ([Absolute positioning inside relative parent](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)). After all troubleshooting fails, I turn to you ;)

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/selman555/DWX92/10/) contains I think is right, but clearly isn't.
Why are the child elements of the parent div positioned relative to the body and not the div?

code:

```
<div id="editorWrapper" style="posotion: relative; width:751px; height:250px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid blue;">
    <a class="lnk" href="http://www.google.be" style="display: inline-block; position:absolute; left: 1%; top: 1%; padding: 5% 5%;"></a>
    <a class="lnk" href="http://www.google.be" style="display: inline-block; position:absolute; left: 80%; top: 80%; padding: 10% 10%;"></a>
    <div style="position: absolute; padding: 10px; left: 60%; top: 60%; background-color: red;" />
</div>
```

**EDIT**
The answer is just a typo. posotion should be position in the parent div.
For future references: this positioning methods does in fact work :)

Thanks Gaurang!

Answer (score 2):

Take note: You have written `posotion: relative` in the style attribute of `div#editorWrapper`. It should be `position: relative` instead.

**[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DWX92/11/)**